# Configurar ProxyPass a otra carpeta

Tags: apache, apache2

Me he quedado sin sitio en el servidor y he tenido que crear otra carpeta HTML2, en el mismo directorio que HTML, es decir:

```
/www/var/html
        /html2
```

Apuntando a otra partición del disco duro.

Hasta ahora con el proxypass, redirigía según subdominio

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName xxxx.yyyy.com
        ServerAlias zzzz

        ProxyPass / http://192.168.1.1/aaaaa/

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
</VirtualHost>
```

Pero ahora me surge la duda de como puedo ir un directorio hacia atrás, para servir contenido del nuevo HTML

Answer (score 0):

Utilizas ProxyPass para servir paginas que están en subcarpetas del mismo servidor?

Porque no utilizas la directiva DocumentRoot?

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName xxxx.yyyy.com
    ServerAlias zzzz

    DocumentRoot /www/var/html2

    <Directory /www/var/html2>
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride FileInfo
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
 </VirtualHost>
```

Te he puesto la directiva de  porque creo que al estar fuera del ServerRoot no tendrá permisos para acceder a los ficheros.

Las directivas que te he puesto en directory son:

- **Options FollowSymLinks**: Seguir los enlaces simbolicos
- **AllowOverride FileInfo**: Permite crear el fichero .htaccess para poner algunas directivas de apache como Rewrite. Si no lo usas lo ponenes a "None"
- **Order allow, deny**: Establece la preferencia de las directivas de acceso. Allow, por encima de Deny
- **Allow from all**: Permite el acceso desde cualquier sitio

** Puedes encontrar mas información aqui: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html

Comment: No, utilizo proxy pass porque las peticiones van a un servidor (192.168.1.1) y las paginas se sirven desde otro servidor (192.168.1.2) que es el que tiene las dos carpetas html y html2

Comment: Ok, entonces podrías crear un Alias en el servidor 192.168.1.1

En el Virtualhost principal del servidor 192.168.1.1 (supongo que solo tendrás uno)
Le añades:

    Alias "/bbbb" "/www/var/html2"
    <Directory "/www/var/html2">
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

*** Puedes revisar aquí la documentación: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html


Al realizar la petición con ProxyPass

    ProxyPass / http://192.168.1.1/bbbb/
Te mostrará lo que tengas en la carpeta /www/var/html2 del servidor 192.168.1.1

O almenos esta es la idea :P